# What should I do when I see a non-programming question on SO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

I don't have enough rep to vote to close.  Should I...

1. vote it down?
2. ignore it?
3. tag it notprogrammingrelated?
4. or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't tag not-programming-related or similar. That's a useless tag. Either

- vote down
- ignore and let users that can, close it
- flag for moderator attention

Comment: I disagree that the tag is useless: It makes it easy for people to ignore not-programming-related posts.

Comment: @sth: That's a moot point. Not programming related posts are not allowed on SO by definition.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how this question got bumped, but it's due for a new answer. The flag system has been extended to let you flag as 'off-topic' as a way of attracting the attention of people with enough rep to vote to close. So that's preferable.

Answer (score 4):

A nicely worded message pointing to the FAQ about what is considered to be an on-topic question usually doesn't hurt.   Don't encourage a user to repost to the another site.

A nice comment will both inform the user, may discourage other people from needless down-voting, miss-tagging, and possibly help other 3k+ people decide to click close or not if they are on the fence about the question.

Comment: yes, polite comments pointing out *specifics* are always welcome, I think

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is to vote for closing, but I realize you do not have the necessary 3000 rep to do so. I would not even flag for moderator attention, as usually a question is viewed and voted on for closing pretty fast. Flag it if it is blatantly offensive.

As Martinho points out, please do not add a useless tag. Nobody searches for it.

Answer (score -2):

Call the stack overflow police!